# Fetching label value of switch in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox, react-native-component

I want to achieve functionality of a **checkbox** with a **switch** in **react-native**, as checkbox isn't supported in **ios devices**. I am not getting on how can I fetch the label value associated with a particular **switch**.
So, the idea is, I have a bunch of options, say A,B,C and each is associated with a **switch**, and there is a **submit** button. On click of **submit** I want to get the labels of those options which are toggled on.

This is the code for selecting various options and each is associated with a switch,

```
       <Text>A</Text>
       <Switch
           onValueChange = {this.handleToggle}
           value = {toggleValue}
       />
       <Text>B</Text>
       <Switch
           onValueChange = {this.handleToggle}
           value = {toggleValue}
       />
       <Text>C</Text>
       <Switch
           onValueChange = {this.handleToggle}
           value = {toggleValue}
       />
```

And handleToggle code is this,

```
handleToggle = event => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        toggleValue: !state.toggleValue
    }));
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same function for different switches, clicking on one of them won't give you access to the label of that particular switch. To do so i would suggest to build it like this. This could be a working solution:

Starting with an array that looks like:

```
this.state = {
   data = [
      {
       label: "firstSwitch",
       checked: false,
      },
      {
       label: "secondSwitch",
       checked: false,
      }
   ]
}
```

Then, in your render:

```
this.state.data.map((item, index) => <Fragment>
      <Text>{item.label}</Text>
      <Switch 
      onValueChange = {() => this.handleToggle(index)}
      />
   </Fragment>
)
```

The `handleToggle` will update the array in the position passed as argument:

```
handleToggle = index => {
   let tempArr= this.state.data
   tempArr[index].checked = !tempArr[index].checked
   this.setState({data:tempArr})
}
```

The submit button will then check for the checked switches:

```
onSubmit = () => {
   let arrOfCheckedSwitches= []
   this.state.data.forEach (item => item.checked && arrOfCheckedSwitches.push(item.label))
   console.log("array of labels :", arrOfCheckedSwitches)
}
```

Let me know if there's something that's unclear